# Rename columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried below but only last column is renamed.

```
output_df.rename(
    columns={"area": "areaNums", "week": "Week", "year": "Year", "price": "PriceColumn"},
    inplace=True,
)
```

I am getting 4 columns area, week, year, PriceColumn instead of areaNums, Week, Year, PriceColumn.

Comment: How can we help if we can't see anything about the original DF?

Comment: Please re-assign back to output_df, rename is not an inplace operation. ie. `output_df = output_df.rename(blah... blah.. blah..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'area': [], 
                    'week': [],
                    'year': [],
                    'price': []
                    })

df.rename(columns={"area": "areaNums", "week": "Week", "year": "Year", "price": "PriceColumn"}, 
    inplace=True
)

print(df)
```

with output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [areaNums, Week, Year, PriceColumn]
Index: []
```

like you need.

Comment: when you say `inplace=True`, the return object is None, so its misleading to call that `output_df`

Comment: @PaulH Is there any other way of renaming all columns at once?

Comment: @user2330678 what's wrong with the `rename` method?

Comment: @PaulH I don't want to create the dataframe, if I don't have to.

Comment: @user2330678 I don't understand. How would you have a dataframe to rename if you didn't create one? Look at the docs on the pandas website for `rename` it's pretty clear how to use it.